# GlM (OpenGl Mathematics) Library stops M_PI and other defined constants from working

Tags: c++, windows, undefined-reference, glm-math

I need the [GLM Library](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) for matrix calculations.

In a large project I use the M_PI constant in lots of places for calculations, I also use the max and min functions.
These comes from the cmath library as so.

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

as soon as the GLM library is included the max min macros and the constants like M_PI stop being available.

**Works:**

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"  //standard stuff
#include "windows.h" //for max, min

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>     //for M_PI
#include <iostream>  //for cin

int main()
{
    printf("Pi is approximately: %.4f", M_PI);
    printf("Biggest of 5.3 and 7.4 is :%.4f\n", max(5.3,7.4));
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Does not compile:**

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"  //standard stuff
#include "windows.h" //for max, min
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>     //for M_PI
#include <iostream>  //for cin

int main()
{
    printf("Pi is approximately: %.4f", M_PI);
    printf("Biggest of 5.3 and 7.4 is :%.4f\n", max(5.3,7.4));
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The M_PI symbol not being defined is caused by `glm` including `cmath` before

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

If this define statement is put before  the glm include it fixes the maths constants problem.

The `max` `min` definitions are from the `"windows.h"` however because the glm library has it's own functions it *undefines* them. This can be seen in a file titled `<glm/detail/_fixes.hpp>` which as the name might suggest is a workaround to a problem when they built the library.

The solution is therefor either `using namespace glm;` or use the functions in the `glm` scope.

All these fixes combined results in

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <cmath> //now redundant as glm includes it
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("Pi is approximately: %.4f\n", M_PI);
    printf("Biggest of 5.3 and 7.4 is :%.4f\n", glm::max(5.3,7.4));
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```